# MediaPlayer do not Play the same song if it is stop

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a app where I've to Play song from Media library using `MediaPlayer`. I'm getting the songCollection and playing a selected song. Problem is I want to play the song again from beginning if I stop the song in between.
when I stop the `MediaPlayer` and again play the song it shows the following error:

`Song playback failed. Please verify that the song is not DRM protected. DRM protected songs are not supported for creator games.`

To play the song in Isolated storage I'm using `BackgroundAudioPlayer`. but BackgroundAudioPlayer do not take `Microsof.Xna.Framework.Media.Song` type Argument.

To Play the song I'm using the following code on click event

```
var track = MyTracks.SelectedTrack; //selectedTrack is Microsoft.Xna.Frmaework.Media.Song type
XnaDispatchTimer.Start();
MediaPlayer.Play(track);
```

Where SelectedTrack is defined as

```
SelectedTrack = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song.FromUri(Title, new Uri(strPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

To stop the player

```
MediaPlayer.Stop();
XnaDispatchTimer.Stop();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you added the Capability ID_CAP_MEDIALIB in your project ?

Comment: Yes, I've added thats why i can fetch the song, and can play but once I stop the MediaPlayer, it do not play again the same song from beginning.

Comment: can you share your code snippet for the same like MediaPlayer the way you are using.

Comment: I've added the code, after stopping it I'm calling the Play event code again to Play.